# Removing any duplications from a python list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I am trying to remove any elements from a list that has a duplication.

The example that I am trying to achieve is:

a, b, c d, g, h, i, d, c, b, a

would reduce down to:
g, h, i

I have found a lot of great ways to remove duplications but I haven't come across a way to remove elements if a duplication exists.
Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Please upload your code?

Comment: ```list(set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']))```?

Comment: `lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] no_dups = set(lst)`

Comment: The question is not asking to remove duplicates

Comment: how many rushers...

Comment: As shows in the dup above `[i for i in values if Counter(values)[i] == 1]` (but you should move the `Counter` creation outside your list comprehension.

Comment: I can not add an answer anymore but how about this: Count the frequency of each element of the list (e.g. using a defaultdict) and then only take those elements with count it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `collections`

```
import collections
a_list = ['a','b','c','d','g','h','i','d','c','b','a']
counter = collections.Counter(a_list)

a_list_final = [key for key,value in counter.items() if value == 1]
print(a_list_final)
    ['h', 'g', 'i']
```